# jQuery - operate values from submit buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, function, submit

I have a form with several submit buttons.
I'm trying to use jQuery so it could take values on "submit" function and operate them.

i'm not good at jQuery ..so for now i only come to this...

```
<form id="buttons">
    <input type="submit" id="light1" value="OFF" />
    <input type="submit" id="light2" value="ON" />
    <input type="submit" id="light3" value="ON" />
    <input type="submit" id="light4" value="OFF" />
</form>

<script>
$('#buttons').submit(function() {
 $.get("data.php", { light1: "ON"} );
  return false;
});
</script>
```

So the thing is how can i instead of this

```
  $.get("data.php", { light1: "ON"} );
```

some how on submit take the **id** of button and a **value** ?
So it could be like

```
 $.get("data.php", { *ID OF A BUTTON*: "*VALUE OF BUTTON*"} );
```

...and operate it?

**Thanks!**

P.S the values of buttons are refreshing with php and jQuery, so no worry about this part ;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the easiest solution would be to catch the event on the button elements, rather than on the `form`.

```
$('#buttons').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // for safety's sake
     var data = {};
     data[this.id] = this.value;
     $.get("data.php", data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#buttons input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var data = {};
   data[this.id] = this.value;
   $.get("data.php", data );
});
```

Comment: This won't work. You can't use a variable as a property name in a function literal.